# C# SerialPort Readline with multiple newline in buffer

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to get some data from a temperature controller using rs232.
The controller sends me an echo for every character at the end of each complete command it returns a '§' and a '.' if if the command was applied successfully. My test code looks like this:

```
static string GetData(int memoryAddress)
 {
     if (!_session.IsOpen)
         return "No Connection";

     string toSend = "*A_r_" + memoryAddress.ToString() + "_0" + (char)21;

     foreach (char character in toSend)
         _session.Write(character.ToString());

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    return _session.ReadExisting();
}
```

and returns something like this:

```
*A_r_0_0§.250§
```

Now I also need to store some data inside the controller and want to reuse the upper part is it possible to use

```
ReadNewline (with Newline-Symbol §)
```

to only get the echo and verify it, so that i can read the returned data (in case i choose to read someting) in the next function?
Which value woud get returned first? the one that arrived last or first?

also would it be better to use a timeout for ReadNewline instead of Thread.sleep(100)?

Comment: Change the NewLine property, so you can use ReadLine(), or use ReadTo().  Never use Sleep() to fix a problem, strongly avoid ReadExisting().  You simply need to call ReadTo() twice, first to get the echo and again to get the response.  Whether you actually use the response is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good to use 'DataReceived' event

```
    private Object responseSignal = new object();
    private string portResponse;
   _session.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(PortDataReceived);

static string GetData(int memoryAddress)
{
   if (!_session.IsOpen)
     return "No Connection";

   string toSend = "*A_r_" + memoryAddress.ToString() + "_0" + (char)21;

   foreach (char character in toSend)
     _session.Write(character.ToString());

  if (System.Threading.Monitor.Wait(responseSignal, 10000)) // max time we want to wait to receive the response
   {
       // successful get
   }   
   else
   {
       //  failed to receive the response 
    }
    return portResponse;
  }

  public void PortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (responseSignal)
            {
                string tmpPortResponse = _session.ReadExisting();
                portResponse += tmpPortResponse;


                //Complete the response only when you get the end character
                if (tmpPortResponse.Contains('.'))
                {
                    // signal allows a waiting SendMessage method to proceed
                    System.Threading.Monitor.Pulse(responseSignal);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't this get called after the first echo (char) arrives so that I still need to wait for the rest to arrive?

Comment: Yes. You can store the data received and signal an event on receiving the end character( '.' ) that you are looking for. It is good to do this way instead of using Thread.Sleep()